# fast way to process json file in Spark

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, etl

I have a set of big compressed json files with nested key-value pairs. There are about 70-80 keys (and subkeys) in the json object, however, I am only interested in few keys. I wanted to query the json files with Spark SQL, only pick out the key-value pairs that I am interested in, and output them to a set of csv files. It takes about 5 mins to process a compressed json file of 170MB in size. I am just wondering whether there could be any way to optimize this process. Or is there any better tools other than Spark for this kind of job? Thanks!

Here is a snapshot of the scala code I was using:

```
val data = sc.textFile("abcdefg.txt.gz")
// repartition the data
val distdata = data.repartition(10)
val dataDF = sqlContext.read.json(distdata)
// register a temp table
dataDF.registerTempTable("pixels")

// query the json file, grab columns of interest
val query =
"""
  |SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, col5
  |FROM pixels
  |WHERE col1 IN (col1_v1, col1_v2, ...)
""".stripMargin
val result = sqlContext.sql(query)

// reformat the timestamps
val result2 = result.map(
  row => {
    val timestamp = row.getAs[String](0).stripSuffix("Z").replace("T"," ")
    Row(timestamp, row(1), row(2), row(3), row(4), row(5), row(6), row(7),
      row(8), row(9), row(10), row(11))
  }
)
// output the result to a csv and remove the square bracket in each row
val output_file = "/root/target"
result2.map(row => row.mkString(",")).saveAsTextFile(output_file)
```

Comment: I;m guessing most of the time goes on the reading/decompressing and writing, which can't be parallelized. Add the overhead of distributing the jobs and collecting the result, and my guess is using Spark is slowing you down here. And why the `repartition` of the un-parsed lines?

Comment: If you just want to transform your data. You don't need all the SparkSQL funcationality. Just stick to RDD's. Use a fast json lib like PlayJson to parse json. Modify it and dump it.

Comment: And please don't do repartition on RDD's unless explicitly required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets say your json data looks like following,

```
{ "c1": "timestamp_1", "c2": "12", "c3": "13", "c": "14", "c5": "15", ... }
{ "c1": "timestamp_1", "c2": "22", "c3": "23", "c": "24", "c5": "25", ... }
{ "c1": "timestamp_1", "c2": "32", "c3": "33", "c": "34", "c5": "35", ... }
```

Now, you can use a json lib and RDD's to do the transformation dump.

```
import play.api.libs.json._

val data = sc.textFile("abcdefg.txt.gz")

val jsonData = data.map(line => Json.parse(line))

// filter the rdd and just keep the values of interest
val filteredData = data
  .filter(json => {
    val c1 = (json \ "c1").as[String]
    List[String]("c1_val1", "c2_val2", ...).contains(c1)
  })

  // reformat the timestamps and transform to tuple
val result2 = filteredData
  .map(json => {
    val ts = (json \ "c1").as[String]
    val tsFormated =  ts.stripSuffix("Z").replace("T"," ")
    (tsFormated, (json \ "c2").as[String], ...)
  })

val output_file = "/root/target"

result2.saveAsTextFile(output_file)
```

Answer (score -1):

It's easy way to process json:

```
        val path = "examples/src/main/resources/people.json"
        val peopleDF = spark.read.json(path)

        peopleDF.printSchema()

        peopleDF.createOrReplaceTempView("people")

        val teenagerNamesDF = spark.sql("SELECT name FROM people WHERE age BETWEEN 13 AND 19") teenagerNamesDF.show()

        val otherPeopleRDD = spark.sparkContext.makeRDD(   """{"name":"Yin","address":{"city":"Columbus","state":"Ohio"}}""" :: Nil) val otherPeople = spark.read.json(otherPeopleRDD) otherPeople.show()
```

see doc: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#json-datasets

Comment: Was this answer helpful?